# No CSS auto-complete with VScode and styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, styled-components, intellisense

I am working with styled-components in a jsx file, when suddenly the auto-completion(emmet?) disappeared. I have the VScode styled-component extension and can't figure out what happened.

it only auto-completes to html properties.

I miss it! and I miss being able to click ctrl+space to see my options

send help.[this is how it looks like when trying to add padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYPvG.png)

[this is how i expect it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7WrA.png)

I have vscode-styled-components extension installed

Also I set

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
```

Comment: Do those two files have the same file extension? It's possible the VSCode extension is only targeting certain file types.

Comment: It worked on both js and jsx files yesterday, now not working on either

Comment: emmet is just the shortcuts thing https://github.com/emmetio/emmet. 
You can check bottom right of vscode to see which file type is recognized, is it javascript react. 
Can also see what version of extension you have and which vscode version.
Also look at output window on vscode and check on Extension Host in dropdown see if any info about the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me.

If you're using version 1.77.0, what worked for me was going back to version 1.76.2 of VSCode.

Look at your version in Help > About

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_76

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue
and I just downgraded the version of vscode-styled-components extension to 1.7.5 and then updated it manually to the current version-1.7.8 and it worked for me.